# Pass changed geom from object to other ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot, grob

I first make a plot

```
   df <- data.frame(x = c(1:40, rep(1:20, 3), 15:40))
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y = x)) +
      stat_density2d(aes(fill='red',alpha=..level..),geom='polygon', show.legend = F)
```

Then I want to change the geom_density values and use these in another plot.

```
# build plot 
q <- ggplot_build(p)

# Change density
dens <- q$data[[1]]     
dens$y <- dens$y - dens$x
```

Build the other plot using the changed densities, something like this:

```
  # Built another plot
    ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y =1)) + 
      geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
      geom_density2d(dens)
```

This does not work however is there a way of doing this?

---

**EDIT: doing it when there are multiple groups**:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:40, rep(1:20, 3), 15:40), group = c(rep('A',40), rep('B',60), rep('C',26)))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y = x)) +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=group,alpha=..level..),geom='polygon', show.legend = F)

q <- ggplot_build(p)
dens <- q$data[[1]]     
dens$y <- dens$y - dens$x

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y =1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = group), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_polygon(data = dens, aes(x, y, fill = fill, group = piece, alpha = alpha)) +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  guides(fill = F, alpha = F)
```

---

**Results when applied to my own dataset**
Although this is exactly what I'm looking for the fill colors seem not to correspond to the initial colors (linked to A, B and C):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this? It is possible to plot a transformation of the shapes plotted by `geom_density`. But that's not quite the same as manipulating the underlying density...

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y =1)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_polygon(data = dens, aes(x, y, fill = fill, group = piece, alpha = alpha)) +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  guides(fill = F, alpha = F)
```

[image]

---

Edit - OP now has multiple groups. We can plot those with the code below, which produces an artistic plot of questionably utility. It does what you propose, but I would suggest it would be more fruitful to transform the underlying data and summarize that, if you are looking for representative output.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y =1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = group), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_polygon(data = dens, aes(x, y, fill = group, group = piece, alpha = alpha)) +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  guides(fill = F, alpha = F) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thankyou Jon that's muchhhhh better than what I did now! I now built the object and edited the original object, rebuild it and changed the axis etc. took my like 15 lines of code.

Comment: Is this also possible with multiple groups (see edit)?

Comment: Didn't get notified with the edit, thankyou for the suggestion for the multi group plot however the fill seem not to correspond to the original as can be seen when `guides(fill = T, alpha = T)` there are  multiple fill colours instead of the three colours for A,B and C (see my edit to see how it looks on my dataset)

Comment: Nearly got is using `geom_polygon(data = dens, aes(x, y, fill = fill, group = group, alpha = alpha))` however the order of the colors seems to change

Comment: What about `geom_polygon(data = dens, aes(x, y, fill = group, group = piece, alpha = alpha)) +`?

Comment: Doesn't work either, maybe it isn't possible at all